# Login and logout via SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have this SignalR / MVC web application I'm building.

I currently have login and logout functionnality using ajax calls.

I would like to have those transit via SignalR instead. Is that possible? I'm having a hard time understanding how the auth cookie is going to be handled.

Currently my controller action login does this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        var nickname = Request.Params["nickname"];
        var password = Request.Params["password"];

        // [Some database stuff...]

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(agencyMember.Id.ToString(), true);
    }
```

So to give this a try, I've setup my logout function in my hub:

```
    public class Proto1 : Hub
    {
    [Authorize(RequireOutgoing = false)]
    public string Logout() {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return "ok";
    }
```

This does'nt work, when I debug, I get a "Response is not available in this context." exception and the logout does not go through.

Am I going wrong about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What's your motivation for wanting to do login and logout with SignalR?

SignalR Hub method invocations do not necessarily correspond to distinct HTTP requests (they can be triggered by a WebSocket message for example). This means that it's not always possible to modify response headers or set cookies when you are inside of a Hub method.

I would suggest continuing to login and logout using Ajax calls.

Comment: The main motivation is speed, the SignalR requests are super fast versus the ajax calls. I could send back the required info as text and have the javascript build that cookie + reinit the signalr communication... (thinking out loud here)

Comment: Logout via ajax in your MVC controller as @halter73 suggests